# Jquery wait till a function with ajax call in loop is completed - Refresh after a Button Click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have some code inside a button click event in jquery. It gets all the radio buttons in a aspx page and it will loop through them according to their clicked status and save them using ajax call (to a function in c# which indeed passes it again to a webservice) one by one.

Now I want to call page refresh function after the saving event. But when I call the event the page is getting refreshed before all the saving could happen and only few of the clicked button are in their new checked status while others are still loaded according to their old status.

So how do i wait till all the saving is done and call the refresh function... I tried jquery when and trigger and few other methods but nothing seem to work..

```
 $('#btnsubmit').click(function() { 
        $('.radioControl:radio:checked').each(function(e, i) {  
            .............      
           commentsAjax.doAjax(...);  //function 
        });   
       refresh();
    });  
 commentsAjax = { 
    doAjax: function(....) { 
        ................
        some function call in C# code which from then goes to a web service  
        success: function(e) {
            //alert('Saved Successfully');         
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your call to refresh is happening inside your each loop, so it looks like you're refreshing the page before the each is finished.  Try moving it outside the each as a first step.

Comment: Sorry its a typo mistake.. i am calling it outside the loop itself

Comment: Will there be multiple Ajax requests running at the time. and you want the event when all request finished ?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use a concept of recursion, or loops with a callback basically.

```
(function recur(elements) {
    var elem = Array.prototype.shift.call(elements);

    if(elem) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/check",
            success: function() {
                recur(elements); //Success, go again
            }
        });
    } else {
        //Done!
        refresh();
    }
})($(".radioControl:radio:checked"));
```

What's happening here is that we first create our `recur` function. You might be familiar with the IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) pattern where we create an anonymous function and invoke it immediately (`(function(){})()`) however in this case, we name it which thus allows us to call said function within it's scope whenever we want to progress in the loop. Next, we send an array of elements and as we slowly progress through the loop, we shift the first item out of the array and send the new, shifted array into the next iteration. This depletes the array until were left with no elements, i.e. finished!

The reason we use `Array.prototype.shift.call` is because a jQuery object is not a native array but has all the necessary elements to allow us to call the native `shift` function on it (which are `length` and the ability to access objects at indexes).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is a *very* bad way to go about things. Instead you should compile and serialize the data and handle it server side. This would reduce the amount of requests to the server which is always a good thing.

Comment: Yes I know but this is a  exisiting apllication.. for some reason client is not willing switch to a more traditional model :|